# Criar pasta e ID simultaneamente usando o mesmo numero de id

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Preciso que na hora que o usuário for inserir uma nova matéria seja criado uma pasta com o mesmo numero do ID do artigo.

```
<?php
include './includes/config.php';
setMenu("Notícias");
include './includes/cabecalho.php';

checkLogin();


$erro="";

if ($_POST['salvar']) // noticia clicou no botao salvar
{
    $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
    $conteudo = $_POST['conteudo'];
    $categoria = $_POST['categoria'];
    $imagem = $_POST['imagem'];
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $autor = $_POST['autor'];
    $destacar = $_POST['destacar'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE (titulo=:titulo)";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam("titulo", $titulo);
    $stmt->execute();
    $noticias = $stmt->fetch();

    if ($noticias)
        $erro=setError("Esse titulo da noticia ja existe !!! Altere o titulo");


    else
        {


            $sqlInsert= "INSERT INTO noticias (titulo,categoria,imagem,conteudo,data,autor,destacar,status) VALUES (:titulo,:categoria,:imagem,:conteudo,:data,:autor,:destacar,:status)";
            $stmt = DB::prepare($sqlInsert);
            $stmt->bindParam("titulo", $titulo);
            $stmt->bindParam("categoria", $categoria);
            $stmt->bindParam("imagem", $imagem);
            $stmt->bindParam("conteudo", $conteudo);
            $stmt->bindParam("data", $data);
            $stmt->bindParam("autor", $autor);
            $stmt->bindParam("destacar", $destacar);
            $stmt->bindParam("status", $status);
            $stmt->execute();

            if (DB::lastInsertId())
            {
            $id = DB::lastInsertId();
           $dir = "../imagens/$id";
           mkdir("$dir", 0777);
                setMessage("Notícia cadastrado com sucesso.");
                redirect("noticiasListar.php");
            }
            else
            {
                $erro = setError("Algum erro aconteceu");
            }
        }
    }



?>

<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <form action="noticiasNovo.php"  method="post">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">

                <h3 class="panel-title"><strong>Novo Notícia</strong>
                    <a href="noticiasListar.php"  class="pull-right "><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
                </h3></div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <?php echo $erro ?>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="noticias">titulo:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="titulo"  name="titulo"  value="<?php echo $titulo?>" placeholder="Titulo da Noticia" >
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="noticias">Categoria:</label> <br>
                                <select class="form-control" name="categoria" id="categoria">
                                <option>Selecione a Categoria</option>
                                <?php 
    $sqlcategoria = "SELECT * FROM categoria ORDER BY nome ASC";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sqlcategoria);
    $stmt->execute();
    $categoria = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($categoria as $u) {
                        echo "<option>{$u->nome}</option>";
                    }

                    ?>
    </select>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="noticias">Imagem:</label>
          <input type='file' class="form-control" id="imagem"  name="imagem" placeholder="Selecione a Imagem" >
         </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="noticias">Preview:</label>
                                <img src="" width="100" height="100" id="preview" /> </div>
                        </div>
                        <br><br>
                    <br>

                                <label for="noticias">Conteudo:</label>
                                <textarea name="conteudo" id="conteudo" rows="10" cols="80">
                <?php echo $conteudo?>
            </textarea>



                        <br>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="noticias">Data:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="data"  name="data"  value="<?php echo $data?>" placeholder="data da publicação" >
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="noticias">Autor:</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="autor" id="autor" required>
                                <option>Selecione o Autor</option>
                                <?php 
    $sqlautor = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY nome ASC";
    $stmt = DB::prepare($sqlautor);
    $stmt->execute();
    $autor = $stmt->fetchAll();

foreach ($autor as $u) {
                        echo "<option>{$u->nome}</option>";
                    }

                    ?>
    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="noticias">Colocar no Slide? </label> <br>
                                <select class="form-control" name="destacar" id="destacar">
            <option selected value="Desativado">Desativado</option>
            <option value="Destacado">Destacado</option>
          </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="noticias">Status</label> <br>
                                <select class="form-control" name="status" id="status">
            <option selected value="Publicado">Publicado</option>
            <option value="Inativo">Inativo</option>
          </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <input type="submit" id="salvar" name="salvar" class="btn btn-default" value="Salvar"></input>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
include './includes/rodape.php';
?>
```

Comment: no teu ```if(DB::lastInsertId())``` vc já está obtendo o ID do registro. Basta utilizá-lo: ```$nomedapasta = DB::lastInsertId();```

Comment: `lastInsertId()` retorna o id do registro inserido, não entendi qual é a dificuldade.

Comment: a dificuldade mesmo é inserir a imagem do post nesta pasta que acabou de ser criada

Comment: Alguma resposta resolver o problema? Acha que alguma pode ser aceita?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para cria a pasta verifique primeiro se o insert não deu erro. Faça uma verificação no execute(). Lembrando que o id só é retornado após o insert ser executado com sucesso e a chamada de lastInsertedId() estar na mesma sessão.

```
if($stmt->execute() === true){
    $id = DB::lastInsertId();
    $nomedapasta = 'pasta_'. $id;
    mkdir = $nomedapasta;

    setMessage("Notícia cadastrado com sucesso.");
    redirect("noticiasListar.php");
}else{
    $erro = setError("Algum erro aconteceu");
}
```

Comment: vlw rray, mais tipo no meu caso eu iria inserir a imagem do post dentro desta pasta, como poderei pegar a imagem depois de ela ja ter inserida?

Comment: Faça uma nova consulta que retorne a imagem ou caminho dela, passando o id inserido.

Comment: passou a duplicar os inserts , porem a pasta esta sendo criada com o numero do 2 insert

Comment: Esse código está dentro de um `for`?

Comment: nao esta, vou editar a postagem colocando o codigo inteiro

Answer (score 4):

Como você não colocou outras partes do código estou considerando que você está manipulando um banco de dados através do objeto `$db`.

```
$ultimoID = $db->lastInsertId();
if ($ultimoID) {
    mkdir("../imagens/" . $ultimoID); //talvez precise colocar permissões mas resolve a dúvida principal
    setMessage("Notícia cadastrado com sucesso.");
    redirect("noticiasListar.php");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Database/LastId.php).

Esta é uma forma simplificada, não dá para responder melhor com tão pouca informação.

Preste atenção no que eu fiz, eu usei variável para não ter que chamar duas vezes a mesma coisa. E não usei variável onde só vou usar uma vez. Na edição da pergunta deu para ver que você fez o oposto. Evitou variável onde usa o valor duas vezes e e criou variável para algo que só usa uma vez.

Eu não conheço bem o PDO mas nenhum exemplo da [documentação](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) mostra o uso do `lastInsertID()` da maneira como você está usando. Mesmo que ela funcione, me parece ser o jeito errado e inseguro de fazer.

Comment: a pasta esta sendo criada porem de alguma forma esta inserindo 2 ids

Comment: Não consigo ver motivo para isto ocorrer. Ou não entendi o que está querendo dizer com isto.

Answer (score 3):

Com a ajuda do @rray e @Maniero deu pra ter uma ideia maior sobre o problema, ele não estava funcionando depois do `if` , bastou colocar depois do `execute` que funcionou.

```
$stmt->execute();

        $ultimoid = DB::lastInsertId();
        $dir = "../imagens/$ultimoid";
        $pasta = @mkdir("$dir", 0777);
```