# Prever o proximo ID do Banco

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mysqli

Bom pessoal estou querendo organizar melhor as imagens das postagem porem para isso preciso saber qual será o proximo ID para que eu verifique primeiro a imagem antes de inserir o resto dos dados.

```
 if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"])) {
$imagem = time() . '_' . $_FILES["foto"]["name"];
$diretorio = 'fotos/ {{{AQUI VIRIA O NUMERO DO ID }}}' . $imagem;
if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["foto"]["tmp_name"], $diretorio)) {
  $error = TRUE;
}
```

estou usando pdo para conexao

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45676/91

Comment: esse dai arrumar o id apos o insert essa minha duvida em questao agora é outra é pegar antes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se seu id estiver com `auto_increment` basta buscar as informações da tabela com o sql abaixo:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'nome_tabela'
```

Pegue o valor da coluna `Auto_increment`

Caso não esteja com `auto_increment` e você está inserindo o id manualmente, basta buscar o maior id ou o último registrado respectivamente:

```
SELECT MAX(id)+1 AS id FROM nome_tabela
```

e

```
SELECT id+1 AS id  FROM nome_tabela ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Basta implementar no seu código da forma que desejar.

Espero que ajude, abraços!

Comment: sim mais nesse caso ai eu so poderia pegar o ultimo id inserido certo ?

Comment: sim, bastar somar +1, terá o próximo! (editei o SQL pra ficar mais claro)

Comment: EX: supondo que o ultimo id é o 40 queria dar um jeito de pegar o 41 mesmo ele nao existindo ainda

Comment: Exato! Com o SQL atual já estou somando 1 para que ele traga o próximo id

Comment: Ficaria mais ou menos assim $sql = "SELECT Nid FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
   $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bindValue(":cid", intval($_GET["cid"]));
   
   $stmt->execute();
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
 $idfuturo= ($results[0]["NID"] + 1);

Comment: Isso aí! :D
não esqueça de trocar o outro id:
SELECT Nid FROM posts ORDER BY Nid DESC LIMIT 1